# Can't set android package as system app on my phone

Tags: android, adb

Hello I have 2 Phones 1 it's work on it and the other not
am trying to make Android Package as system \

```
$ adb shell
$ mv /sdcard/base.apk /system/app/
$ cd /system/app/
$ chmod 644 base.apk
```

also tryed 
`$ adb shell am start com.****` 
didn't work 
it's work fine
but in the other phone oppo 1201 Color os App never show app i tryed different launchers didn't work
can please some one told me why this dumb phone wont show apk as system or there system linker verify those applications !

Answer (score 0):

Oppo runs Color OS which is heavily customised over android. It has a lot of restrictions compared to stock android, Oppo only has read access over its system partition. So you might need root access to move files into a system folder. Consider rooting your phone if you really want to do this.

Comment: it's rooted (-_-)